# Redirect Loop on /wp-admin when changing Wordpress URL

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to change the URL for my site, by going to settings in wp-admin and changing both site url and wp url.

[image]

All seems well after I save changes, I'm able to navigate around my blog using the new url. However when I try accessing wp-admin I'm getting a redirect loop. I can still access the wp-admin login page with the old url admin site. In order to access my admin page again I have to login to my DB and reset both urls.

I've also tried to add this code with my urls to my wp-config file

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.sample.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.sample.com');
```

Other information about my setup:

1. Openshift is hosting wordpress with the quick start app and proper alias have been added to my app.
2. Cloudflare is managing my DNS

I wouldn't think either of these factors would be the issue because the site wouldn't work at all if one of these were misconfigured, but at this point I'm drawing a blank. Was thinking maybe it might have something to do with wordpress forcing SSL for wp-admin?

Answer (score 2):

Found It!

I love how when you gather all the information to ask a proper question it seems to line you up for the solution.

I'm also using http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect to redirect naked domain request to www using an A record in my DNS. All I had to do was turn off cloudflare's protection to this DNS entry.

[image]